# How to put a v-btn in the same row as v-expansion-panels?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have some problems aligning my layout. The idea is to have a single set of `v-expansion-panels` in the same row with a `v-btn`, and have both of them visually centered inside a card. I almost achieved it in this codepen: https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/PoPPbdw with this structure:

```
      row
      / \
    col  col
 (panel) (btn)
```

**Problem**: `v-col`'s minimum width creates a whitespace around the button, offcentering the card content visually. Would appreciate some help on how to either:

1. Make the `v-col` surrounding the `v-btn` the same width as the `v-btn`
2. Solve the layout without grid system

Big thanks for anyone thinking along!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it by calculating how much width the `v-col` with the button needs and applied styling in-line in the v-for loop:`<v-col cols="1" style="max-width:40px">`.  Edited pen: https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/KKddyzy

Answer (score 0):

All you have done is right, you just need to warp the `<v-container>` inside the `<v-card-text>` so that it gets a proper alignment. Also, the button in right doesn't need to have a col-2 width, it only needs a col-1 width. Since you haven't given any col width for the  which wraps the button, it's taking the entire space and hence the container also. Another option is to set the width of the container using css eg: `<v-container style="width:600px;">`

```
<v-card color="grey lighten-3">
  <v-card-text>
    Problem: v-col with the <v-icon color="green">mdi-check</v-icon>button has min col width that off-centers the general look. How can the margins on left and right be visually equal? 

   <v-container> //Either give a width here style="width:600px;"
      <v-row v-for="(item,i) in 5"
        :key="i" class="mb-1" no-gutters justify="center">
        <v-col cols="10">
          <v-expansion-panels>
            <v-expansion-panel>
              <v-expansion-panel-header>Item</v-expansion-panel-header>
              <v-expansion-panel-content>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
               </v-expansion-panel-content>
            </v-expansion-panel>
          </v-expansion-panels>
        </v-col>
        <v-col> //or set cols="1" here
         <v-btn class="closeBtn mb-1 ml-1" width="36px">
           <v-icon color="green">mdi-check</v-icon>
         </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-card-text>
 </v-card>
```

Comment: Thank you for thinking along! <3 
I tried adding cols="11" and cols="1" respectively and wrapping container with v-card-text, but I still saw the same offset on the right side. I tried applying a max-width styling to the button col in-line like so: <v-col cols="1" style="max-width:40px"> and it actually seemed to do the trick. Do you think that's a viable solution? https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/KKddyzy

Comment: Yup, that is the width that the button actually needs, this helps other columns to scale and utilize the reset of the available spaces. :D